# Should I Buy A Sony PCM-M10?

Tags: sony, pcm-m10, m10, portable-recorder, field-recording

I have a first generation M-Audio Microtrack (which I'm not a fan of) and was looking to pickup another portable recorder that I can fit in my pocket and barely notice it's there.

This guy is getting good reviews but I was wondering what you guys thought.  Have any of you tried recording quiet ambiences with it?  How does it sound?  How do you like the digital "ghost" limiter?

Thanks,

Mike

PS:  I've read this review and it pretty much has me sold, I'm just looking for more first hand opinions:  http://dot.cult.bg/esem/?pcmm10

Comment: the review from the dead link is at http://esem.name/?pcmm10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came from the Edirol R-09 and the M10 was perfect really.  The internal mics are good (especially for ambience stuff - check out the Nature Recording Group as there's a good few people who like it there and comparisons between the D50 and M10 were damn close).  Mics are omni so not as suited to direct fx recording as the D50  but I use mine with a Sound Devices portable pre and a hyper cardioid anyway.  Its no 7xx series as someone said but it does give you a lot of flexibility when combined with the pre.

I dithered over the m10 vs D50 too but couldn't justify the nearly 40% extra cost (at the time) for the D50.  I hoped after the M10 release their might be a bargain D50 around but it still looks like the D50 price is holding.
Size-wise it is that bit smaller than the D50 and a bit more discreet which is handy 
Windshield is a must....

Answer (score 2):

I bought the M-10, as it's my first pocket sized recorder I think it's great.

I don't know if you'd "barely notice it's there," but it's extremely portable.  Haven't tried to record anything too incredibly quiet, but what I have recorded sounds great using an external mic or the on-board mic. While it does have some plastic, it's a pretty sturdy piece of gear. As far as the limiter goes, I don't think I've turned it on yet, so I can't really lay claim to it's "ghostliness."

Two things I'd recommend if you do buy one. First is the [M-10 wind furry](http://pro.sony.com/bbsc/ssr/cat-audio/cat-recorders/product-ADPCM2/) or something like it, one weekend trip to the beach proved that was desperately needed. The second is a [gorillapod](http://www.amazon.com/Joby-Gorillapod-Original-Flexible-Camera/dp/B001BFJF8Q). I had one of these lying around for my point-and-shoot and threw it in my recording bag, best thing I could have done. Works fantastically.

Comment: +1 - the Gorillapods are brilliant with the M10 - hang mine off tree branches for leaf/wind rustles and all sorts

Comment: +1 on the wind furry. We have a few PCM-D50s at work (what can I say they're handy at times), but it definitely benefits from having the wind protection. It go over way to easy in the smallest amount of wind, and I'd imagine the M10 would probably be similar.

Answer (score 1):

I have a PCM-D50 and I'm very happy with it.  I considered the M10 but got nervous about reports of all the plastic parts.  The D-50 is very sturdy and sounds decent.  You can also position the mic's a bit.  I keep it in my bag all the time.  The cost is a little higher but there are deals online if you search.

Comment: I have quite a bit of experience with the D-50 as well, and can vouch that it sounds good and can survive a tumble.

Answer (score 0):

I'd pony up for the PCM-D50 if you can swing it. My coworker has an M-10 and he's not a fan...

Comment: And I have the PCM D-1 and I love it...it's traveled around the globe with me.

Comment: another vote for the PCM D-50 here.  Have mine, love mine.

Comment: I was trying to stay away from the D-50 because I fear I wont take it everywhere because it's slightly larger.  I was looking for something along the size of an iPod.

Comment: Understood...just think the D-50 is perfect compromise between size and audio fidelity.

Answer (score 0):

(i wrote that review) 
if you're coming from the microtrack, then you'd love the m10. the plastic creaks. that's about as flawed as it gets. maybe the d50 is better in terms of build or preamp, but it's more expensive too.